# Validator stuck in Pending State

Tags: parity, poa, kovan

I am working with a `kovan validator` set for a `POA network`. When I try to add validator, I make the `Initiate Change` call and it goes through. Validator goes to `pending state`. When I make the `Finalize Change` call, it is stuck in pending. Does any one know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all other nodes have to agree on the change. Most likely they are offline and cannot see this new change.